# useContext not rerendering component on change of context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I know there are several posts with same title but I think I have checked all of them and none (of what I have found) apply in this situation.

I have code with main files:

**AuthContext:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import IUser from "../models/ILoggedUser";

export interface AuthContextProps {
  user: IUser | undefined,
  loginUser: (data: any) => void
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContextProps>({
  user: undefined,
  loginUser: (data: any) => {}
});

function AuthProvider({children}: any) {

  const [authContext, setAuthContext] = useState<AuthContextProps>({
    user: undefined,
    loginUser
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authContext?.user?.token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'bearer ' + authContext?.user?.token;
    }
    console.log("changed authContext to: ", authContext)
  }, [authContext])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("changing authContext to: ", loadUserFromStorage(), authContext)
    setAuthContext({
      user: loadUserFromStorage(),
      loginUser
    });
  }, [])

  function loadUserFromStorage(): IUser | undefined {
    if(localStorage["loggedUser"] != undefined) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage["loggedUser"]);
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  function loginUser(data: IUser): void {
    setAuthContext({
      user: data,
      loginUser
    });
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
          {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

**ProctedRoute:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Redirect, Route, useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router";
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  Component: () => JSX.Element;
  path: string;
} 

const ProtectedRoute = ({Component, path}: ProtectedRouteProps) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CHANGE: ", authContext)
  }, [authContext])

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={props =>
        (authContext?.user) ?
          <Component /> :
          <Redirect to={{ pathname:"/login" }}/>
      }
      />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**App:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Redirect, Route, useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router";
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  Component: () => JSX.Element;
  path: string;
} 

const ProtectedRoute = ({Component, path}: ProtectedRouteProps) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CHANGE: ", authContext)
  }, [authContext])

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={props =>
        (authContext?.user) ?
          <Component /> :
          <Redirect to={{ pathname:"/login" }}/>
      }
      />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

- setting AuthContext to new object, not mutating existing state - CHECKED
- having everything inside <AuthContext.Provider> - CHECKED
- the component which should rerender has "useContext" in it - CHECKED

**But when I setAuthContext to new value, ProtectedRoute doesnt rerender -> can anyone give me advice why?** The whole code is available on github (https://github.com/Dan102/task_manager_clone/tree/master/task-manager-client/src)

Comment: Once you hit the `ProtectedRoute` when not logged in the `Redirect` gets loaded and you are not on the `ProtectedRoute` anymore so there is no chance to re-render.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank you, you are indeed right! thanks to you I was able to fix my app.